# Problema de salida con mi algoritmo de karatsuba en c++ para multiplicar 2 números

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Tengo un problema con mi algoritmo en c ++, este código puede multiplicar 2 números en binario, decimal y hexadecimal.

Con los datos de entrada: número de dígitos del primer número, la base de los números y 2 números para multiplicar.

La implementación funciona perfectamente con un máximo de dos números con 2 dígitos cada uno, pero cuando intenté introducir, por ejemplo, `3 10 300 10` (300 * 10) **el resultado es 3000 pero la salida es `2999`** cuando se compila en mi computadora, pero cuando lo ejecuto en un compilador en línea, funciona perfectamente y no sé por qué.

Agradecería si saben cual es el motivo de este problema. Por si hace falta comentar, yo usé visual studio code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int longnum,base;
string num1,num2;
int Tam(string);
string AumCeros(string,int);
bool casobase(int);
int productonormal(string,string,int);
string dividir(string,char,int);
string Bin(int);
string NumHex(int);
string Hex(int);
string Convertir(int,int);
string sum(string,string,int);
bool potdos(int);
int potceros(int,int);
long int multiplica(string,string,int,int);
string Verbase(string,int);
int main(){
    cout<<"\t== Practica 1 Divide y Venceras =="<<endl;
    cin>>longnum>>base>>num1>>num2;
    if(Tam(num2)!=longnum){/*Misma longitud de ambos numeros*/
        num2=AumCeros(num2,longnum-Tam(num2));
    }
    int ceros=0;
    if(!potdos(longnum)){/*Buscar que la longitud de los numeros sea de potencia de dos*/
        ceros=potceros(longnum,1);
        num1=AumCeros(num1,ceros);
        num2=AumCeros(num2,ceros);
        longnum=longnum+ceros;
    }
    long int salida=multiplica(num1,num2,longnum,base);
    string Respuesta=Verbase(Convertir(salida,base),base);
    cout<<Respuesta<<endl;      
    return 0;
    
}
int Tam(string s){//Tamaño de un string
    return s.length();}

string AumCeros(string s,int c){//Aumenta ceros
    if(c==0)
        return s;
    else
        return AumCeros(s="0"+s,c-1);}

bool casobase(int n){//Caso base para divide y venceras, longitud de numero=1
    if(n==1){
        return 1;}
    else{
        return 0;}
}

int productonormal(string x,string y,int base){//Multiplicacion base para divide y venceras
    if(base==16){
        int n1=stoi(x,nullptr,16),n2=stoi(y,nullptr,16);
        return n1*n2;}
    else{
        int n1=stoi(x),n2=stoi(y);
        return n1*n2;}
}

string dividir(string s,char l ,int n){//Seccion de dividr de divide y venceras
    if(l=='d'){
        return s.substr(n/2,Tam(s)/2);}
    else{
        return s.substr(0,Tam(s)/2);}
}

string Bin(int num){//Conversion de un numero a binario en string
    if(num==1){
        return "1";}
    else if(num==0){
        return "0";}
    else{
        string res=to_string(num%2);
        return res+Bin(num/2);}
}

string NumHex(int num){//Seleccion de numero en hexadecimal
    switch (num%16){
        case 10:return "A";
        case 11:return "B";
        case 12:return "C";
        case 13:return "D";
        case 14:return "E";
        case 15:return "F";
        default:return to_string(num%16);}
}

string Hex(int num){//Conversion de un numero a hexadecimal en string
    if(num<15){
        return NumHex(num);}
    else{
        string res=NumHex(num%16);
        return res+Hex(num/16);}
}
string Convertir(int resultado,int base){//Conversion de numeros
    if(base==10){
        return to_string(resultado);}
    else if(base==2){
        return Bin(resultado);}
    else{
        return Hex(resultado);}
    }

string sum(string x,string y,int base){//Suma para divide y venceras Metodo Gauss
    int n1=0,n2=0;
    if(base==10){
        n1=stoi(x),n2=stoi(y);}
    else{
        n1=stoi(x,nullptr,base),n2=stoi(y,nullptr,base);}
    int suma=n1+n2;
    return Convertir(suma,base);
}
bool potdos(int n){//Si un numero es potencia de dos
    if((n&(n-1))==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;}
int potceros(int n,int pot){//Ceros necesarios para alcanzar longitud de un num potencia de dos
    if(n==pow(2,pot))
        return 0;
    else if(n<pow(2,pot))
        return pow(2,pot)-n;
    else
        return potceros(n,++pot);

}
string Verbase(string s,int base){//Paso final para la concersion de la suma a un string
    if(base==10){        return s;}
    else{   
        string n=s;
        reverse(n.begin(),n.end());
        return n;}
}
long int multiplica(string x,string y ,int n,int base){//Metodo Divide y Venceras
    if(casobase(n)){
        return productonormal(x,y,base);}//Caso Base
    else{
        string xi,xd,yi,yd,sx,sy;
        int p1,p2,p3;
        xi=dividir(x,'i',n);//Division --
        xd=dividir(x,'d',n);
        yi=dividir(y,'i',n);
        yd=dividir(y,'d',n);//--
        p1=multiplica(xi,yi,(n/2),base);//Recursividad--
        sx=Verbase(sum(xi,xd,base),base);
        sy=Verbase(sum(yi,yd,base),base);
        int desborde=0,nuevan=n;
        if((n/2)!=Tam(sx) || (n/2)!=Tam(sy)){
            if(Tam(sx)>Tam(sy)){
                sy=AumCeros(sy,Tam(sx)-Tam(sy));}
            else{
                sx=AumCeros(sx,Tam(sy)-Tam(sx));}

            if((n/2)!=1){
                desborde=potceros(Tam(sx),1);
                sx=AumCeros(sx,desborde);
                sy=AumCeros(sy,desborde);
                nuevan=Tam(sx);}
            else{
                nuevan=2;} 
        }
        else{
            nuevan/=2;}
        p2=multiplica(sx,sy,nuevan,base);
        p3=multiplica(xd,yd,n/2,base);//--
        return ((pow(base,n)*p1)+(pow(base,n/2)*(p2-p1-p3))+p3);
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cómo `3 10300 10` significa 300 * 10, como tampoco entiendo cómo introduciendo tres números estás leyendo cuatro: `cin>>longnum>>base>>num1>>num2`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster entiendo que es una errata. el segundo parámetro es la base. En este caso la base es 10, luego la entrada, entiendo, debería ser `3 10 300 10`

Comment: He probado el código y funciona, es decir: [hace lo que se espera](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lhlE2oGztndFLl5t) no lo que el autor de la pregunta describe. Pero el código necesita muchas correcciones, claro que eso se sale del objetivo de la pregunta.